# How to do TDD with log4net?

Tags: c#, logging, tdd, log4net

I'm trying to do TDD, I'm not clear on how to do it for logging logic that I write.

Fox example, what would be a test for following:

```
  if(importantCriteriaNotMet)
  {
     log.Info("My message here");
  }
```

How would I test that logging code?
Should I be testing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If log is of ILog type:

- Mock your ILog interface
- Inject your mocked object
- assert that log.Info is called when importantCriteriaNotMet is true

Comment: If log.Info throws an exception while logging this will not catch any failures of log4net. Would any TDD technique ensure that logging actually works?

Comment: Don´t bother testing if log4net works. It does if you configure it correct. Even if it works in your unit test if you make the effortand  checking a logging file or similar, that´s no guarantee that it works in your production environment.

Comment: As @Glenn suggests don't bother testing log4net. In my example you are only testing YOUR logic that is Info method is called. In this way you are covering all your code paths.

Answer (score 6):

Log4Net:s Logger implements an interface called ILog if I remember correctly.
Use a mocking framework like Moq and create a mocked ILog instance.

Then you design your class to get a ILog instance in the constructor.
Using a design like that you can give the class a concrete implementation when running your system and the mocked instance while running tests.

The you can verify if the logging i done properly with code like this:

```
mockedLogger.Verify(l=>l.Log("The message that should be logged"),Times.Once)
```

If you want to learn TDD mocking is your friend.